# How do I create a custom FilterRule with an override for ElementPasses

Tags: revit-api

I want to create my own Boolean operation on an element to pass in as a **FilterRule**.  The **ElementPasses** member description states:

> Derived classes override this method to implement the test that determines whether the given element passes this rule or not.

I have tried to create my own derived class but I can't figure out how to implement it.  I would think an interface would be available but I can't find anything.  Annoyingly, I remember seeing an example of this but I can't seem to find anything.

This fails with: *Static class 'ParameterDefinitionExists' cannot derive from type 'FilterRule'. Static classes must derive from object.*

```
static public class ParameterDefinitionExists : FilterRule
{
    public static bool ElementPasses(Element element)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this fails with:*'FilterRule' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments*

```
static public class ParameterDefinitionExists : FilterRule
{
    new public bool ElementPasses(Element element)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

What constructor arguments does it take?

There may be another way to go about it but I can't anything for FilterRules.  I'm trying to define and refine a trigger in an updater but maybe I should query the element after it is passed in to the command.  I imagine catching it with a filter rule is more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use one of the Revit API classes derived from `FilterRule`:

**Inheritance Hierarchy**

- System Object

  - Autodesk.Revit.DB FilterRule

    - Autodesk.Revit.DB FilterCategoryRule
    - Autodesk.Revit.DB FilterInverseRule
    - Autodesk.Revit.DB FilterValueRule
    - Autodesk.Revit.DB SharedParameterApplicableRule

Cf. http://www.revitapidocs.com/2017/a8f202ca-3c88-ecc4-fa93-549b26a412d7.htm

[The Building Coder](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com) provides several examples creating and using parameter filters:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/08/elementparameterfilter-with-a-shared-parameter.html

Here is the entire [topic group on filtering](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.9).